# tomcat shut down through process id (windows)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I want to stop the Tomcat process by its process ID. How can I get the Tomcat process ID using Java?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps for the Windows case, but the `catalina.sh` script that you can use on Linux / UNIX can be told to store the PID of the process in a file.  You just need to set the `CATALINA_PID` environment variable to the pathname of your PID file.  When you've done this, running `catalina.sh stop -force` will attempt a clean shutdown, and if that fails it will `kill` the Tomcat process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to access the PID that I am aware of, however, someone has written a great Blog on how to do this indirectly. Here is a link to his 5 different options.

http://blog.igorminar.com/2007/03/how-java-application-can-discover-its.html

The nicest option is this one...

> Using the java management and
>   monitoring API (java.lang.management):

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
```

> returns something like:
>   28906@localhost where 28906 is the PID
>   of JVM's process, which is in fact the
>   PID of my app.
>
> This hack is JVM dependent and I
>   tested it only with Sun's JVM.
>
> From Javadocs for getName() method of
>   RuntimeMXBean: Returns the name
>   representing the running Java virtual
>   machine. The returned name string can
>   be any arbitrary string and a Java
>   virtual machine implementation can
>   choose to embed platform-specific
>   useful information in the returned
>   name string. Each running virtual
>   machine could have a different name.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute TASKLIST.EXE in java and garb the result. the second option I found intresting is  to run Service stop command from java.

Hope it helps.