# Determine if Tomcat is running in Windows using the command prompt

Tags: windows, tomcat, batch-file

Quite simply, how does one determine whether or not Tomcat is running in Windows, using the command prompt?

I am writing a batch script that must do this. This is the [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) version:

```
RESULT=`netstat -na | grep $2 | awk '{print $7}' | wc -l`
```

Where $2 is the port.

I am looking for something similar to that. Using [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) is out of the question, of necessity this script must be able to run on machines that only have Tomcat.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116957/tomcat-shut-down-through-process-id-windows/4117061#4117061 - it might be slightly irrelevant, but you could possibly see how catalina.bat does it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Comment: First make sure that path to Tomcat is setup correctly, by running any command like: **C:\>javap javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest**. If you can see any result, then Tomcat is setup well. Go ahead and check whether Tomcat is running or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use tasklist to check if the tomcat executable is running. For example:

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq tomcat.exe" | find /C /I ".exe" > NUL
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :running

echo tomcat is not running
goto :eof

:running
echo tomcat is running

:eof
```

It is also possible to check a remove server using the options `/S`, `/U` and `/P`. See `tasklist /?` for details.

Comment: shows me that tomcat is running, even when the tomcat service is stopped by user.

Answer (score 6):

Test the status of the Tomcat Service with the [SC](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) command. MJB already suggested to test the service status with SC, yet another batch script (without FOR loop) for testing the status:

```
@ECHO OFF
SC query tomcat5 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO Stopped
) ELSE (
    ECHO Running
)
```

If you are not sure if the service name is *tomcat5* you can list all service names with

```
SC query state= all | FIND "SERVICE_NAME"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [WMIC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx)

```
@echo off
wmic process list brief | find /i "tomcat.exe"
set result=%ERRORLEVEL%
if "%result%"=="1" echo "not running"
if "%result%"=="0" echo "running"
```

note : /i is to make the find operation case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Windows version of the netstat based UNIX/LINUX solution asked in the question:

```
@echo off

netstat -na | find "LISTENING" | find /C /I ":8080" > NUL
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :running

echo tomcat is not running
goto :eof

:running
echo tomcat is running

:eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not very good with scripts but perhaps you could use this as a starting point:

> netstat -a -n | findstr :8005

To get if someone is listening in port 8005. That is Tomcat's default port for remote administration, i.e. startup or shutdown.
Alternatively you could use the port that the http server listens to.
Hope this helps

Comment: When I try to run that, I just get, "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: You need a space between `findstr` and `:8005`.Whithout the space you will get this error you say

Answer (score 1):

use netstat -a in command prompt.

You'll find 8080 port listed there.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Tomcat for Windows **not like a service** and don't want to exploit JMX the best way is

```
for /F %%I in ('tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Tomcat" /NH') do if %%I==java.exe goto alreadyRun
```

where:

- Tomcat - the window title of the Tomcat's terminal window by default
- java.exe - the name of the Tomcat's processe. **NOT tomcat.exe**.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, since this is probably running as a service

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%A IN ('SC QUERY tomcat5 ^| FIND "STATE"') DO SET status=%%A
echo "%status%"
```

status can be things like STOPPED, RUNNING ...

Answer (score 0):

I check it by calling a vb script from command line

```
cscript //nologo checkurl.vbs | findstr "200"
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO :not_running
```

Save the below script as checkurl.vbs and replace the ip with machines ip

```
' Create an HTTP object
myURL = "http://10.1.1.1:8080/"
Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )

' Download the specified URL
objHTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
On Error Resume Next
objHTTP.Send
intStatus = objHTTP.Status

If intStatus = 200 Then
    WScript.Echo intStatus
Else
  WScript.Echo "Error Connecting"
End If
```

I had problems with using `sc query` command, because even if tomcat crashed, the service would still be shown as running where in actual the port was not accessible

Answer (score -4):

You can try searching for the process and extracting the line

For example:

```
ps|grep tomcat
```

Comment: Works on linux. Question is for windows.