# How to check if a Tomcat service is running or stopped in windows through a Java program?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a service is running via batch file and start it, if it is not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325081/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-via-batch-file-and-start-it-if-it-is-not-r)
>   [Determine if Tomcat is running in Windows using the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220196/determine-if-tomcat-is-running-in-windows-using-the-command-prompt)

Is there a way to check if Tomcat service (or any service for that matter) is running/stopped in Windows OS through a Java program running through Windows scheduler? If stopped I have to start that service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a service is running via batch file and start it, if it is not running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325081/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-via-batch-file-and-start-it-if-it-is-not-r) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220196/determine-if-tomcat-is-running-in-windows-using-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the tomcat process looks like. If it is something like tomcat.exe then you could use the solution in the question to get the processes. [How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) and then do a search for the process name